# How to focus input when the screen gets rendered

Tags: html, react-native

Is there any props in TextInput Componenet? ,If Yes, tell me or comment below . Thanks in advance

```
 <TextInput
      style={styles.numberContainer}
      label="phoneNumber"
      id="phoneNumber"
      required
      ref={inputRef}
      autoFocus={true} //   ref={num}
      keyboardType="phone-pad"
      returnKeyType="next"
      onChangeText={val => validator(val)}
      onEndEditing={e => {
             validator(e.nativeEvent.text);
      }}
/>
```

Comment: ref.current.focus() in your case inputRef

Comment: @Freestyle09 Can you explain clearly?. It showing undefined is not an object

Comment: See this example: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput ref={inputRef}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Not working..Can u tell, How can u will implement this in react native

Comment: It's working fine you can see it's implementation here https://snack.expo.io/OTCw65TZ8